# Can't create sqlite3 db through console as shown in the Flask Web Development book

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm not sure what the problem is so I will give as much information as I can and hopefully someone will catch what is going wrong.

The book shows me how to design objects that SQLAlchemy will use to create the database. Then from console I must do the following:

```
(venv) $ python hello.py shell
>>> from hello import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

This is supposed to create a database file in my application directory, which it does not. The line from hello import db works fine.

```
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine='sqlite://'>
```

`db.create_all()` returns no errors, however the database file is not created in my application directory. I want to call attention to this line (is it correct?):

```
app.config['SQLALECHMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite') #Final value: 'sqlite:////home/nick/dev/flare/data.sqlite'
```

Here is my entire hello.py file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, url_for, redirect, flash
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'random key'
app.config['SQLALECHMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite') #Final value: 'sqlite:////home/nick/dev/flare/data.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True

manager = Manager(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
moment = Moment(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role %r>' % self.name


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

class NameForm(Form):
    name = StringField('What is your name', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        old_name = session.get('name')
        if old_name is not None and old_name != form.name.data:
            flash('Looks like you have changed your name')
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=session.get('name'))

@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    return render_template('user.html', name=name)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

Comment: (not an answer, but found this helpful). I've been reading the same book. tbh, I never quite like how it did the `manage.py` file. [I always preferred doing it this way](https://gist.github.com/DarkCrowz/df4e656b9a55a7523118), just so that way you can do `python manage.py seed` to create a fresh db and add some users, and you can also choose the config by using `--config [which config]` as an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the configuration:

```
app.config['SQLALECHMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
```

That's a misspelling of `SQLALCHEMY` there, it should be:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
```

Because you misspelled it, the default `sqlite://` is used, an in-memory database.

Comment: I should have known it was a typo. Wish I could delete this now.